# Can Cantor's diagonalization argument be used to enumerate real numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Cantor's diagonalization argument relies on the assumption that you can *construct* a number with infinite length. If that's possible, could you not start with a random real number and use the diagonalization to get the next unique real number and continue this never-ending process as a way of enumerating all the real numbers?

Can you really claim in this case that you can still find a number not in the list by using diagonalization again?

Comment: I think the main issue is that if you construct a list, the list is already infinite and supposed to contain every real number. You cannot apply Cantor diagonalization again to add another element because the list is already set. Maybe someone can make this rational more formal.

Comment: There is no way to tabulate the reals.

Comment: The argument can't be used to do that because it proves nothing can do that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how, after doing the first diagonalization, you propose to run it a second time to get a next real number? I wasn’t sure I saw how you were doing that.

Comment: @templatetypedef I would start with a random irrational number. Change the 1st digit after decimal and get the next irrational number. Do the diagonalization on the previous two to get the next irrational and so on.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you can produce the "next" real number from any "previous" real number does not imply that you can put all the real numbers in a (countable) list.

In fact, you don't need to pull Cantor for this. Just for the argument's sake, let's regard real numbers in $[0,1)$ and let the next real number after

$$0.a_1a_2a_3a_4\ldots$$

be the number you would obtain by incrementing $a_1$, except if it is $9$, bring it to $0$ and increment $a_2$, except if that one is also $9$, bring it to $0$ and increment $a_3$ - similar to how you would turn dials on the mileage counter. So, let the next real number after

$$0 = 0.000000\ldots$$

be

$$0.1 = 0.100000\ldots$$

and then $0.2, 0.3, \ldots, 0.9, 0.01, 0.11, 0.21, \ldots, 0.99, 0.001\ldots$.

and, to show you that it works for all sorts of real numbers in $[0,1)$, the next number to $\frac{1}{3}=0.333333\ldots$ is $0.433333\ldots$ and the next number after $\pi-3=0.14159265\ldots$ is $0.24159265\ldots$.

Do you now see how your argument does not allow you to conclude that you can *enumerate* all the real numbers? Specifically, starting from $0$ you never reach any real number which has an infinite decimal expansion.

Comment: I see. I think I meant to say irrational numbers, not all reals.

Comment: I did not prove that it is not possible. (For that, you have Cantor's diagonal argument.) I *poked a hole in your purported proof that it is possible*. In other words, showed you why your reasoning is incorrect. Applied to all reals, or to irrationals only, it is incorrect either way. By the way my map above actually maps irrational numbers into irrational numbers and can be used to build a counterexample for your reasoning just the same. (Start with $\sqrt{2}-1=0.4142\ldots$ and you can never get $\sqrt{3}-1=0.732\ldots$. Why? Because $\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$ is itself irrational.)

Comment: So, you're saying that if I start with an irrational number and do diagonalization there will still be numbers that I could never get to? I don't find it obvious that you could not get to 0.732... from 0.4142... using diagonalization.

Comment: Sure, there will always be numbers that you cannot get to. Because, well, say you've done it and you've finally listed all real numbers. Then take your final list and *do diagonalisation one more time*. That is the essence of Cantor's argument. My argument above is about something else: I think you are assuming something like this: "*I can find the 'next' real number for every real number $\implies$ I can use that to put all real numbers in a list*", and I am showing you that this argument is flawed.

Comment: Yes, that's the argument that I'm making. I meant to use diagonalization as a way to enumerate the irrational numbers just like adding 1 would be a way to enumerate the natural numbers. You would never say you've listed all the irrationals just like you would never say you've listed all the natural numbers. Diagonalization here is a way to enumerate the irrationals so you can keep going forever just like the natural numbers.

Comment: But ... I *would* say I listed all natural numbers. I will explain: by "listed all $X$" I mean I've created a bijective map $\mathbb N\to X$ so that $1$ maps to the first element of $X$, $2$ to the second etc. In this case you can just map every natural number $n$ to itself. *That* is what I mean by "listed all $X$". I am not sure what *you* mean when you say that. Anyways, in the above sense all real numbers *cannot* be listed, because whatever *injective* map $\mathbb N\to [0,1)$ you choose, Cantor's argument shows that there is a real number not mapped to by this map... (TBC)

Comment: (Cont'd) ... i.e. the map cannot be surjective. Thus it cannot be bijective. For irrational numbers then it follows that you cannot list them all either, because if you could list irrational numbers $i_1, i_2, i_3,\ldots$ and knowing you *can* list all rational numbers $q_1, q_2, q_3,\ldots$, you would automatically have listed all the real numbers like this: $q_1, i_1, q_2, i_2, q_3, i_3,\ldots$. The bottom line is - Cantor's proof is watertight but you and I may disagree about what we mean by "list all real numbers".

Comment: (In the above, I use the freedom to represent a map $\mathbb N\to X$ which is, technically, $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&\ldots\\x_1&x_2&x_3&\ldots\end{pmatrix}$ as merely $x_1, x_2, x_3\ldots$. For example, the map that maps every natural number to itself can then just be written as the sequence $1,2,3,\ldots$ rather than more technically $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&\ldots\\1&2&3&\ldots\end{pmatrix}$.)

Comment: Okay, but there could be an arbitrary bijection in my case also, couldn't it? Map the first to 1, create the second by diagonalization and map that to 2, create the third with diagonalization and map that to 3...? What would be wrong with that?

Comment: It will be an *injection* but not a *bijection*. It won't be "onto". You will miss a real number. Which one? Well, take all the real numbers you've generated, all the infinitely many of them together! Then *apply diagonalization once more*. You will get a real number that is not in your list. Thus your list will not contain all real numbers. No matter how you make it: diagonalization, some other algorithm, taking them randomly (and throwing away in the unlikely case you've got a duplicate) - completely irrelevant. You've made your list somehow - well, there is a real number not on the list.

Comment: (And you can get it by applying diagonalization once more to the entire infinite list you've already made.)

Comment: I don't understand why _applying diagonalization once more_ should do anything (I've raised this question on the original question too). If someone claims that they found an irrational number x.xxx...... that is not on my list, I can see that I wouldn't be able to say the exact natural number that would map to x.xxx..., but can I not say that eventually there will be some natural number that maps to it? Why should someone else be able to stop me and say I've already made an infinite list when the process of enumeration by diagonalization would go on infinitely?

Comment: Because the number obtained by diagonalization is *definitely* not on your list. It differs from the first number on the list on the $1$st decimal place, from the second number on the $2$nd decimal place, ... from the $n$th number at the $n$th decimal place etc. - by the very nature of the diagonalization procedure. (Or do we disagree in what we mean by "diagonalization"? - hopefully not!)